# File corrupted after computer shutdown(power-off) in netbeans

Tags: netbeans

Iam using netbeans 6.9 for PHP , the file i was working on  corrupted after computer shutdown(power-off) , despite i save it after every change i make ( web developers know that )
so is there any way to recover the file ? when i open the file in netbeans it show just blank with spaces , when i open it in notepad++ , it show just NULL char ..
(My OS : WINDOWS 7 )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be using source control. Take this as a lesson and install SVN, GIT, mercerial or even visual source safe (wait no don't do that).

I don't know about ellipse, but [my editor](http://www.editplus.com/) creates a versioned auto backup every time I save the file. It is VERY nice to have the history of all file changes.

In terms of the file you were working on, you are screwed. The amount effort it to try and recover it would be greater than redoing your changes from a backup. You do have a backup right?

Comment: i take a backup at the end of the day.. , but the file i working on just  corrupted

Comment: That is why you have source control. Do not write another line of code until you are using it. Good luck!

Comment: i setup subversion and today i worked with, its better much work with  , Thanks for your suggestion :) ..

Answer (score 1):

See the answer here:
[Can I search Netbeans' local history?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8587687/can-i-search-netbeans-local-history)

You can recover some files form the Netbeans history.