# Is there a way to recover a PHP file that has been corrupted by Netbeans?

Tags: php, netbeans

I was working on a PHP file which is about 500 KB in size on Netbeans 7.0.1 on Windows 7. Unfortunately, the laptop powered off suddenly at the same moment while I'm saving the file after some edits (Bad luck, I know). When I tried to open the file again it shows just blank spaces without any codes although the file size is still 500 KB!

Is there anyway to recover this file (is not strange that it still has the same size ?). Does netbeans save any temp files or backups for the files in that case?

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried opening the file in another editor? Maybe the problem is with netbean's cache or something.

Comment: Tried using Notepad (windows) and TextEdit (Mac) and Titanium. No way :(

Comment: The history might help you, see the answer here:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8587687/can-i-search-netbeans-local-history

Answer (score 0):

Click on the history tab, it should show you the history of the file:

[image]

---

worst case, check your remote FTP host, it should still be right up there...

Comment: I can not find the history tab. I'm using Netbeans 7.0.1 on Windows 7. Where is it ?

Answer (score 0):

I had same thing. Been working on a project when PC rebooted. Few files which were saved lately and all their history got zero filled. 
First thing, you should check history tab (it's on editor's toolbar, which is under tabs by default. if it's not not, you can enable it under View ->show editor toolbar), maybe you're luckier than I am. In case your history got zero filled too, you could try some program to recover files, R-Studio for example. Either by trying to recover earlier versions of history or files or you could use its inbuilt viewer to search for pieces of files. I know it's tedious and long process but I actually got few files back this way.

Lesson should be learned: Always store your files on remote host for back up purposes.

Comment: Thanks for your input. I'm using Netbeans 7.0.1 on Windows 7 and I can not find (Source - History) tabs below the editor toolbar. I checked "Local History" in the right click menu of the file and it shows that there are no history for the file.

Comment: I'll give R-Studio a try. But do you know any other recovery software as its trial is limited to around 80 KB files.